# How to combines multiple DB queries in RXJava

Tags: java, rx-java2

I want to execute two queries one after another where the second query is dependent on the first query and finally I want to return a combined result.

```
public class Order {
    private int orderId;
    private int productId;
    private Date orderData;

    public Order(int orderId, int productId, Date orderData) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.orderData = orderData;
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order{" +
                "orderId=" + orderId +
                ", productId=" + productId +
                ", orderData=" + orderData +
                '}';
    }
}


public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;

    public Product(int id, String name, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", quantity=" + quantity +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Program {

    static List<Product> productList;
    static List<Order> orderList;

    static {
        productList = Arrays.asList(
                new Product(1, "Shoe", 10),
                new Product(2, "Shirt", 5),
                new Product(3, "T-Shirt", 2),
                new Product(4, "Belt", 20)
        );

        orderList = Arrays.asList(
                new Order(1, 1, new Date()),
                new Order(2, 1, new Date()),
                new Order(3, 1, new Date()),
                new Order(4, 2, new Date()),
                new Order(5, 3, new Date()),
                new Order(6, 3, new Date()),
                new Order(7, 4, new Date()),
                new Order(8, 4, new Date()),
                new Order(9, 4, new Date()),
                new Order(10, 4, new Date())
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getAllProductWiseOrderDetails()
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Single<Map<Product, List<Order>>> getAllProductWiseOrderDetails() {
        Map<Product, List<Order>> details = new HashMap<>();

        getProducts()
                .subscribe(
                        products -> products
                                .stream()
                                .forEach(product -> {
                                    getOrders(product.getId())
                                            .subscribe(orders -> {
                                                details.put(product, orders);
                                            });
                                })
                );

        return Single.just(details);
    }

    private static Single<List<Product>> getProducts() {
        return Single.just(productList);
    }

    private static Single<List<Order>> getOrders(int productId) {
        return Single.just(
                orderList.stream()
                        .filter(order -> order.getProductId() == productId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );
    }
}
```

I wanted to know what would be the best way to implement the getAllProductWiseOrderDetails() method so that I can get full utilization of RxJava. I am using this approach where I am subscribing two times which I don't think is a good approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the content of the result you want to have, based on the `Product` and `Order` instances you have in `productList` and `orderList`.

Comment: I want to return Map which contains a Product-wise Order list, for each product, there may be 0 or more than 0 Orders.

Comment: Why do you want to use rx-java for this? The requirement is not really "stream/reactive based". A normal `for` loop or some kind of `grouping()` operator should be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: I want to use rxjava because it is the project requirement. It is a sample code but in reality this data of functions getProduct() and getOrder() is a db functions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the project requirement you have. Using `Single()` calls to use `subscribe()` for that single value makes it unnecessary complicated when a simple `for()` loop might solve the problem. You might want to add a [mcve] which shows the architecture/system you have in your program and how rxjava is used there.